# How to permanently leave a CALayer rotated at its final location?

Tags: cocoa, calayer, caanimation, cabasicanimation

I am trying to rotate a CALayer to a specific angle however, once the animation is done, the layer jumps back to its original position. How would I rotate the layer properly so that it stays at its final destination?

Here is the code that I am using

```
CABasicAnimation *rotationAnimation =[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"]; //Rotate about z-axis
[rotationAnimation setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:fromDegree]];
[rotationAnimation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:toDegree]];
[rotationAnimation setDuration:0.2];
[rotationAnimation setRemovedOnCompletion:YES];
[rotationAnimation setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
```

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I fixed it by setting removeOnCompletion to NO.

```
[rotationAnimation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
```

Comment: An anonymous editor says: "This is not the correct answer. The proper way to make the final value 'stick' is to set the transform property of the layer to the final value for the animation." (from edit review; I voted to reject because it should be a comment; I have no opinion on whether they're correct)

Comment: rotationAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;  works too

Answer (score 2):

You're adding an animation, but you aren't modifying the actual underlying property. After you create the animation, just set the layer's `transform` property to contain the same final result.